# Missing preview tab in Birt layout

Tags: java, eclipse, birt

Just installed new version of Birt 4.x in eclipse and couldn't find preview tab in layout window.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Preview tab has been moved to toolbar option. You can find it on the toolbar with planet earth icon [image] or under menu Run > View Report

With the latest version you can test your report in different formats( pdf, xls...)

Answer (score 6):

The preview tab has been removed in BIRT version 4.4.0. See the following link for details: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=421879

Comment: The documentation and tutorial still refer to it, and it's 2018.